# Copying all folders except those containing a "skipthisfolder.txt" file

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, copy, directory

I want to do a script that does the following :

- COPY All folders and all files from "D:\"  to  "F:\"
  but
- SKIP all folders containing a "skipthisfolder.txt" file

Which scripting language should I use?  (in order to run it easily in Windows, without any third party software?)  I thought about .BAT or VBS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a CMD batch file, like this:

```
@echo off
for /r D:\ %%a in (.) do (
  IF NOT EXIST "%%~fa\skipthisfolder.txt" XCOPY "%%~fa" "F:%%~pna"
)
```

**EDIT:** if you also need to skip subfolders if `skipthisfolder.txt` file is found, then this could be a solution:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off

set skip=@

for /r D:\ %%a in (.) do (
  echo %%a | findstr /c:"!skip!" > nul
  if !errorlevel!==1 IF EXIST "%%~fa\skipthisfolder.txt" set skip=%%~dpna
  echo %%a | findstr /c:"!skip!" > nul
  if !errorlevel!==1 XCOPY /D "%%~fa" "F:%%~pna"
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this !

And do you know a method for selecting all folders that don't contain this "skipthisfolder.txt" file  in Windows's explorer ?

Maybe with some "Search" field in Windows's search tool.

Comment: i don't think it's possible with just windows explorer, without third party software

Comment: Thanks again.
What command can I use in order to evaluate total size of all folders (except those with "skipthisfolder.txt") before copying them ?

Comment: If I want to overwrite files that have changed only  (not copy files that are already present on destination and identical), can I use 
`XCOPY /D ... ...` ?

Comment: i don't know how to evaulate total size without using thid party software... but to skip idendical files and owerwrite only never ones, yes you can use /D

Comment: You can evaluate size using `%~za`, then just put that in a variable and keep adding to it to find the size of the folder.

Comment: Thanks again!
Is it possible to export a list (in a txt file) of all folders that will be selected ?  (one folder per line)
If so, then I may find their size with another soft...

Comment: Thanks Bali C,  how can you use `za` ?

Comment: Is there an option for XCOPY such that DESTINATION has to be identical to SOURCE (ie  if a file is in DESTINATION and not in SOURCE, it has to be deleted)
It seems to be possible with ROBOCOPY. But is it possible with Xcopy ?

Comment: i don't think it's possible with XCOPY but you could use ROBOCOPY, it should be ROBOCOPY /purge /xo "%%~fa" "F:%%~pna" (i have not tested it yet!). How do you launch the command? Did you put it in a .CMD file or at the command line?

Comment: Now I have been able to make your solution with XCOPY work.

But... Subfolders of a folder that has `skipthisfolder.txt` are copied as well. They shouldn't be copied. Do you know how to solve this?

Comment: I'm still a little bit lost...

How to exclude ALL subfolders of a folder containing the `skipthisfolder.txt` file ?

Comment: Thanks so much fthiella for your last edit!

May I ask you a last thing ?

Is it possible to calculate and display size of all folders that will be copied (with `%~za`),  then `pause`, and then your script that does the copy ?

I tried for some hours, but I'm unable to do it...

Comment: @thiella : sorry, but I can't make your last solution work :

I replaced your `D:\ ` with `"D:\My Documents\mp3"`, and your `F:` with `F:\Sounds` (which is my real destination folder)  but it doesn't work.
The folder names aren't respected, the files are all copied in `F:\Sounds`, all mixed in this folder.

Comment: there's still something to fix, if there is a skipthisfolder.txt file in a subdir that has to be excluded, things could be messed a little, but except for that it should work... let me give a look! If you also want to calculate the size of the folder... yes we can do it, but i think it's better if you add a new question for it!

Comment: could you try to add an `echo` before `xcopy`, to see exactly what it does? it looks good to me...

Comment: added a check to ignore `skipthisfolder.txt` files in subdir that are already excluded. it looks okay to me now...